# How to get the search result as a list in vimscript?

Tags: vim

How to get the search result as a list in vimscript, without outputing to the quickfix window?
(I need to search in only the current buffer)

I thought of two ways to get a result list:

1. `while` and `search()`.
2. `vimgrep`, then get data by `getqflist()` and clear the quickfix window.

But neither seems efficient enough.
Is there better solutions?

My script:

```
fun! GetAnn()
    let ls = getline(1, '$')
    let ann = []
    let i = 0 | whi i < len(ls)
        let annl = { 'row': i, 'ann': [] }
        let j = 0 | whi 1
            let r = matchstrpos(ls[i], '(.\{-})', j)
            let j = r[2]
            if j == -1 | brea | endif
            call add(annl.ann, { 'col': j, 'txt': r[0] })
        endwhi
        if len(annl.ann) > 0
            call add(ann, annl)
        endif
    let i += 1 | endwhi
    retu ann
endfun
```

Comment: `search()` seems like a fine solution. What do you mean "not efficient enough"?

Comment: You can also copy the buffer in to a variable or register, and then use `match()`, `matchlist()` or `matchstr()`.

Comment: An example can help a lot.

Comment: For me as a beginner, `search()` is like a kind of user action (`/`).Now I find it's not the case. Thanks! @XPlatformer

Comment: @MarcosPérez I worked out the example (It works) (upd in the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit loop + calling search/match functions is indeed damn slow with vim 8.x (I haven't tested Vim9 scripting language yet). It's better to work on lists like the one returned by `getline()`.

So, if you're just searching in the current buffer, you could use

```
:echo getline(1, '$')->filter({_,line -> line =~ 'regex'})
```

or with older versions of vim

```
:echo filter(getline(1, '$'), {_,line -> line =~ 'regex'})
```

or with even older versions of vim

```
:echo filter(getline(1, '$'), "v:val =~ 'escapedregex'")
```